# Android kotlin : How to turn an image into MultipartBody?

Tags: android, kotlin

It takes a list of images and tries to send them one by one to the server.

After receiving the image list from the main, pass it to Content Uri Request Body and change it to RequestBody.

After that, I changed the request Body to Multipart.body and sent it to the server.

But the server returns me the message "The browser (or proxy) has sent a request that this server cannot understand."

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_OPEN_GALLERY) {
        if (data?.clipData != null) {
            binding.writingFramelayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            val count = data.clipData!!.itemCount
            if (count > 10) {
                Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.select_image), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
                return
            }

            viewModel.imageUriList.clear()
            for (i in 0 until count) {
                val imageUri = data.clipData!!.getItemAt(i).uri
                viewModel.imageUriList.add(imageUri)
            }
            binding.writingImageImageView.setImageURI(data.clipData!!.getItemAt(0).uri)

            if (count > 1) {
                binding.writingImagesTextView.let {
                    it.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    it.text = "외 " + (count - 1) + "장"
                }
                
            } else {
                binding.writingImagesTextView.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        } else {
            data?.data?.let { uri ->
                viewModel.imageUriList.clear()
                viewModel.imageUriList.add(uri)
                binding.writingImageImageView.setImageURI(uri)
                binding.writingImagesTextView.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a code that adds a list to the viewModel after selecting multiple images in the fragment.

```
private fun changeType(contentResolver: ContentResolver): ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part> {
    var imageRequestList = ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part>()

    for (i in 0 until imageUriList.size) {
        val requestBody = ContentUriRequestBody(contentResolver, imageUriList[i])
        val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", "imageUri", requestBody)
        imageRequestList.add(body)
    }

    return imageRequestList
}
```

This is a method to change the view model to Multipart.body.

```
class ContentUriRequestBody(
    private val contentResolver: ContentResolver,
    private val contentUri: Uri
) : RequestBody() {

override fun contentType(): MediaType? {
    val contentType = contentResolver.getType(contentUri) ?: return null
    return contentType.toMediaTypeOrNull()
}

override fun writeTo(sink: BufferedSink) {
    val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(contentUri)
            ?: throw IllegalStateException("Couldn't open content URI for reading: $contentUri")

    inputStream.source().use { source ->
        sink.writeAll(source)
    }
}
```

}

This is ContentUriRequestBody

Comment: Hi @minhee welcome to SO! The `RequestBody` (ContentUriRequestBody) implementation could be at fault. You can bypass it and use `RequestBody.create` constructor for a check.

Comment: I tried RequestBody.create by making it a file, but it failed. ㅜㅜ..